Nix: SSL error while downloading narinfo files
I am trying to make nix work behind zscaler. I am getting an error while executing this command
nix-shell -p nix-info --run --show-trace --verbose "nix-info"

This is the error message:
warning: error: unable to download 'https://cache.nixos.org/': SSL connect error (35) OpenSSL/3.0.14: error:16000069:STORE routines::unregistered scheme; retrying in 273 ms

I have tried multiple things with pem files, like providing rootCA of organization to NIX_SSL_CERT_FILE environment variable, combining rootCA with cert.pem, but nothing is working
